# How to run tests in multiple environments like qa, prod and staging in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

In my project I have to run robot tests on multiple environments like QA, Prog and Staging. Scenario is like I have to launch application in browser based on input I'm giving from the command terminal to execute robot test. example: If want to launch application on QA environment with chrome browser. I'm passing environment details and browser details along with execution command. Please help me in understanding above scenario with example.

Thanks,
Sudheer

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file named config.py in this format:

```
## PRODUCTION
PROD_URL = 'https://production.test.com/'
PROD_User_1 = 'user_prod'
PROD_Pass_1 = 'password_prod'

## STAGING
STAGING_URL = 'https://staging.test.com/'
STAGING_User_1 = 'user_prod'
STAGING_Pass_1 = 'password_prod'
```

Then, you can import it on your testing file

```
*** Settings ***
Variables       config.py

*** Variables ***
${ENVIRONMENT}              STAGING
```

Then you can easily call it anywhere in the file like this:

```
${${ENVIRONMENT}_User_1}
```

You can also run in the terminal by passing the specific variable for ENVIRONMENT, like this:

```
-v ENVIRONMENT:PROD
```

Comment: I'd go with similar approach too but i'd have separate config.py file for each environment and have same variable names  so that actual "robot" code does not need to have variable varibles ..

Comment: With above approach its not working. If possible can explain with open browser example

Comment: You can open the browser by doing: Open Browser    ${${ENVIRONMENT}_URL}   Chrome